# How to read the properties file in app engine application?

Tags: file, google-app-engine

I am reading properties file from the folder (/war/config/client.properties) in my google appengine application. It is working fine in my local server but it is not working in production mode, and it is throwing exception java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission).

Could you please tell me how to make it work in the production mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load it like this if you put it in WEB-INF/classes :

```
InputStream is =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/client.properties");
```

Similarly you could do

```
InputStream is = this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/client.properties");
```

Then:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(is);
String whatever = props.getProperty("whatever_key");
```

Per the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?hl=en-US#The_Sandbox :

Anything in war should work by default:

Make sure you haven't excluded anything in appengine-web.xml ):

```
  <resource-files>
        <exclude path="**.properties"/> ...make sure you haven't done this
  </resource-files>
```

Anything in war should work by default should work so **try reading from `/config/client.properties`**

java.io.FileReader definately will.

or

```
InputStream is = this.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/config/client.properties");
```

Comment: I did n't put it in the WEB-INF,how to load from the external folder which is in war folder?

Comment: Anything under war should be a resource unless you exclude it. Try /config/client.properties